# Slow query when sorting large data

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query:

```sql
select h.id
from history h
where
    h.processed = false
order by coalesce (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)
limit 5
```

executes fast (6ms), because almost every row has `processed = true`. But when I change to this:

```sql
explain analyze 
select h.id
from pgz75008.history h
where
    h.processed = true -- the only change is here
ORDER BY coalesce (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)

limit 5
```

now execution takes over 1.5 seconds (260x times more than previously). This is my index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON history USING btree (processed, last_process_attempt_time, delivery_time);
```

First query plan:

```sql
Limit  (cost=18242.80..18242.81 rows=5 width=45) (actual time=6.866..6.869 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=18242.80..18468.04 rows=90095 width=45) (actual time=6.863..6.864 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (COALESCE(last_process_attempt_time, delivery_time))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Index Scan using test_idx on history h  (cost=0.43..16746.36 rows=90095 width=45) (actual time=0.034..6.601 rows=1149 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (processed = false)
Planning Time: 0.309 ms
Execution Time: 6.904 ms
```

second query plan:

```sql
Limit  (cost=331050.32..331050.92 rows=5 width=45) (actual time=1497.691..1631.789 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=331050.32..1127312.50 rows=6650224 width=45) (actual time=1484.761..1618.855 rows=5 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Sort  (cost=330050.26..334206.65 rows=1662556 width=45) (actual time=1420.135..1420.138 rows=4 loops=5)
              Sort Key: (COALESCE(last_process_attempt_time, delivery_time))
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 2:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Worker 3:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on history h  (cost=0.00..302435.80 rows=1662556 width=45) (actual time=11.190..1000.568 rows=1347834 loops=5)
                    Filter: processed
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 230
Planning Time: 0.233 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 21
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 8.992 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 5.794 ms, Emission 61.213 ms, Total 75.999 ms
Execution Time: 1634.044 ms
```

Any ideas how can I make it faster?

Comment: Your description is inconsistent.  You say the fast query is testing for true, but the fast plan itself says it is testing for false.

Comment: @jjanes you're right. I edited a question

Answer (score 0):

What if

```
select h.id
from history h
where id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM history h2 where h2.processed = true)
order by coalesce (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Booleans are difficult to be useful in an index, since you have only three options: null, true and false. Pretty easy to be useless.

What if you create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_last_process_attempt_time_delivery_time
ON history (
  COALESCE (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)
);
```

Maybe it's useful to include the processed column, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_last_process_attempt_time_delivery_time
ON history (
  COALESCE (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)
)
INCLUDE (processed);
```

Comment: I agree having index with only 3 possible values will be useless.Creating the index with `COALESCE (h.last_process_attempt_time, h.delivery_time)`  will definitely have better performance.

Comment: @KennethChirchir One column with 3 values can be very useful as part of a multicolumn index. On its own it probably isn't so useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the coalesce expression if you want that expression to use the index.

There are many possible ways to formulate this, but the most straightforward is this one:

```
 create index on history (processed, coalesce(last_process_attempt_time, delivery_time));
```